# Record in Android Emulator flickers

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I have tried recording in Android Studio with different emulated devices and programs, but all my records flicker heavily.

The screen of the emulator itself doesn't flicker.

I have tried using Nexus 5X, Nexus 7 and Pixel 2 on 25 and 28 API level.

I'm running the emulator on Windows 10 with Intel Core i7-4720HQ, 16GB memory and NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970M.

I have set the mode to Maximum Performance in NVIDIA Control Panel.

When I record the same programs with real phone, everything works fine.

The version of Android Studio is up-to-date.

Comment: Same issue there... Any solution?

Comment: Have the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Same problem, ended up using Kazam.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I had the same problem and I have solved it by changing a parameter in the emulator's `config.ini` file

To solve it, you go to the path in your machine where the emulator devices are located, example: `C:\Users\XXXX\.android\avd\`

Enter the directory of the emulator that you want to fix, open the `config.ini` file in a text editor and where it says:

```
hw.gpu.mode = auto
```

You replace it with:

```
hw.gpu.mode = guest
```

Save the changes and restart the emulator.

Comment: This should be marked as the answer. Is there any explanation for this anywhere?

Comment: FYI: The file to be searched and edited is: `hardware-qemu.ini`

Comment: Used the Android Device Manager to change device settings, the *guest* option wasn't in the list so manually typed and saved. Worked a charm thanks!

Comment: I changed it. but after restart the emultor, text file is reverted to default. Why?

Comment: @zihadrizkyef same here :(

Comment: "hw.gpu.mode = guest" makes emulator so slow. 
this solved my problem:
Logcat -> record screen -> uncheck "Use Emulator Recording (webm)" 
then start recording

Comment: @DavidArchanjo No its not. Its config.ini

Comment: This happens to me on my live test devices (Samsung). Currently the only two options on the screen recorder are 'Bit rate (Mbps)' and 'Resolution (% of native)' with 100%, 50% and 30% options. Reducing both of these to the minimum doesn't help.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue and was able to solve it by changing Emulated Performance to "Software-GLES 2.0" in the AVD settings. In the notes, it says that this setting is supposed to be used to work around issues with the computer's graphic card.
(This solution is similar to the one of @padDad, just with a different setting)

[image: Screenshot of solution in AVD Manager]

Answer (score 8):

I managed to fix this problem by changing Emulated Performance to Hardware -GLE 2.0 from AVD

[image: Emulated Performance to Hardware -GLE 2.0]

Answer (score 5):

Try by unchecking "Use Emulator Recording (webm)".

[image]

Comment: you can insert an image into the body of the response, since the image on the link can be deleted.

Comment: I am not sure why this answer didn't get votes!! Unchecking the webm solved my issue without changing GPU or bit rate! It also automatically save as MP4.

Comment: @MohsenMirhoseini This options is not available in old versions of android studio.

Comment: @AliSed but the old Android Studio was recording fine :)

Comment: If you are wondering where to change that setting, it appears when you record from the logcat tab. It works for me that way and recording in mp4.

Comment: @AliSed maybe time to update :)

Answer (score 3):

Try to change the preferred graphic processor to "Integrated graphics". At my computer it is not solved the problem, but it reduce the flickers dramatically.

**NVIDIA Control Panel -> Manage 3D settings ->Program Settings**:

Then, select the emulator (qemu-system-x86_64.exe) or add it to the list, and select **Integrated graphics** instead of **NVIDIA processor**

[image: S]

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing the same problem playing back recordings from an Android emulator.  I worked around this problem by setting the emulator property hw.gpu.mode off.

Comment: I tried setting hw.gpu.enabled to false in the virtual device's config.ini but this problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason trying above method, i.e. changing emulated performance to either software or hardware, still does not work for you then try this as well:

[image]

- Making [ bitrate ~ desired framerate ] works for me hence 24 instead of default 4 Mbps
- Instead of 1080 x 2220 I used 1088 x 2224 in order to make it multiple of 16.

When saving the video try saving it in .mp4 format instead of .webm (if not already mp4)

[image]

I have followed steps mentioned here in order to record my emulator screen: [How to screen record emulator in android studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-video)

Answer (score 1):

Running the emulator with `-gpu guest` works, but makes the emulator a lot slower.

Upgrading the emulator from version 32.1.14.0 to 33.1.24.0 fixed the issue for me. I can now record with `-gpu host` without flicker.

Answer (score 0):

This is because nvidia gpu, I switch to use my intel Xe using Graphic option in windows 11 System->Display->Graphics then add qemu-system-x86_64.exe in application list then choose power saving (using intel xe than nvidia rtx 3050)